# Why my flutter-quill error and cannot running even though i change the version?

Tags: flutter, dart

> flutter_quill-5.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:233:7: Error: Thenon-abstract class 'RawEditorState' is missing implementations for these members:
>
> - TextInputClient.didChangeInputControl
> - TextInputClient.performSelector
>
>   Try to either
> - provide an implementation,
> - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
> - mark the class as abstract, or
> - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

```
class RawEditorState extends EditorState
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1163:8: 
Context: 'TextInputClient.didChangeInputControl'is defined here.

    void didChangeInputControl(TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl{}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1184:8: 
Context: 'TextInputClient.performSelector' isdefined here.

    void performSelector(String selectorName){}
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i already did **flutter upgrade** and update or change **flutter quill version**, but the problem still same.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

1. Do not forget to add "hide Text" after the import of flutter quill:

   import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' hide Text;
2. I have also ran into this issue and the way I solved it was by reinstalling flutter.